# Test Driven Development. How do I handle refactoring untested legacy code?

Tags: refactoring, tdd, legacy-code

I am beginning to adopt Test Driven Design (TDD) behaviors and workflow for my iOS development projects. There is at least one impediment though in the context of legacy software. I will often have to add features to a pre-existing code base that I am new to. I will typically want to refactor at the beginning of working with the code base which will often have no tests available to ensure that my refactor-ings are not altering code functionality or worse, adding bugs.

My question is how do TDD folks bootstrap the whole process when the code is not written from scratch but rather legacy code that they are brought in to work on?

Thanks,
Doug

### UPDATE

For a concrete example, I am using the example from Martin Fowler's Refactoring re-coded in Objective-C as a training device for TDD (and AppCode) [>>](https://github.com/turner/RefactoringFirstExample)

I built the code from tests. I found I needed to add instance variables to the Customer class to ensure I didn't screw up the cost calculations in the **statement** method as I grew the code. This is the fundamental issue I need insight into.

Comment: Michael Feather's book, Working Effectively with Legacy Code, is a good start

Comment: @LukeHutton - Dude, thanks so much for this pointer. This is EXACTLY what I need to be reading right now. Really, really helpful. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, if you don't understand the legacy code you're working with, you need to fix that before you do things which you're concerned may change behavior.

In your situation, after understanding the legacy code, I would write tests that will run against that legacy code. Once you're satisfied that these tests function as you expect, you're in a much better position to test your refactored code to ensure it functions as the old code did.

Comment: +1 - I was about to write the same thing.  One thing I would add is that writing these tests will help you understand the code better because you can (should be able to anyway) step through the code with a debugger to aid in your learning.

Comment: @mah, lets take the simple example from the beginning of Martin Fowler's Refactoring. In the "statement" method in his code example there are simple algorithms used to compute rental cost. These are buried in the code with no obvious way to observe them from a test. Importantly, their behavior could easily change/break as I refactor as we can plainly see as Fowler goes through his stages of refactoring. Here states at the top he has the confidence to make these refactoring moves because he has test to fall back on if he breaks something. I will not have that luxury with legacy code.

Comment: @austin, I totally agree refactoring will be a vehicle for gaining understanding. My concern is that - code being code - I could easily blindly break something - perhaps subtley - during the course of my refactoring. Oh, and I specifically hope to avoid sitting in the debugger. That is a BIG reason I am going the TDD route in the first place.

Comment: @dugla:  With legacy code, you have to assume the current behavior is correct so you write tests that confirm that assumption.  Going forward, you audit those tests and adjust accordingly.